# Javascript regex : uppercase ratio

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Is there a way to calcultate the uppercase/lowercase ratio and block with JQuery Validation Engine if there are too much uppercase?

This is to avoid uppercase only messages, but I need to allow some uppercase for acronyms.

My concern is that a message can be 10 or 400 characters long, so I can not define a limit like

```
/^(?!(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){50})/
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: why using a regex for this, you can simply count the number of uppercase letters in a message. No regex needed, you can even count consecutive letters being uppercase or simply all uppercase letters. Then derive a ratio based on message length

Comment: even simpler `message===message.toUppercase()` checkes if the message is all uppercase

Comment: Unefortunately I believe JQuery Validation Engine only accepts regex

Comment: @Jibeji: No you can have custom functions. See [custom\[function_name\]](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#customfunction_name) and [funcCall\[methodName\]](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#funccallmethodname).

Comment: @Nikos and Sani, thank you !